# How to get a physics raycaster to fire in the direction that a player is looking in Unity Google VR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-vr

In the game which I am making, a player is supposed to select different objects by looking at them. To do this, I am trying to script a physics raycaster to fire in the direction that the player is looking at (direction of camera). Typically I would just add the gvrrecitlepointer prefab to the camera, and place event triggers on each object, but this won't work since I am using objects which are constantly changing.

When I try 
`Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward);` no ray appears.

The main problem is that the second argument in debus.drawray or physics.raycast takes a Vector3, while camera position is a quaternion.

I made a script for the camera which gets the camera rotation into a variable

`gamers = Camera.main.transform.rotation;`

and then in my original script put in

`epicgaming = new Vector3(GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<camerarotationvariables>().gamers.x[...]`

`Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, epicgaming);`

which tries to convert the quaternion into a vector, but although the values match up, running the program causes the ray to fire in random uncontrollable directions.

How can I get Debug.DrawRay/Physics.Raycast to actually fire in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: When you have enough reputation, you can edit and add a bounty to this question so it gets an answer.